# How to change ControlWrapper Category filter ui.caption text color based on the caption?

Tags: google-visualization

How to change ControlWrapper Category filter ui.caption text color based on the caption? I tried like following code,but it not works.

```
var category_Picker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                          'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
                          'view': {'columns': [1,2,3,4,7,8]},
                          'containerId': 'category_filter_container',
                          'options': {
                            'filterColumnLabel': 'P/A',
                            'ui': {
                              'matchType':'any',
                              'label': '',
                              'caption':'All',
                              'labelStacking': 'horizontal',
                              'allowTyping': false,
                              'allowMultiple': false,
                              'cssClass':'category_Picker_Class'
                            }
                          },
                          'state':{'selectedValues':['A']}
                      });

var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                                  'chartType': 'Table',
                                  'containerId': 'summary_details_table',
                                  'options': {'allowHtml': true,'alternatingRowStyle':true,'width':'100%','height':'600px'}
                              });

// Create the dashboard.
var data_DashBoard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('summary_details_table')).bind(category_Picker, table).draw(view);

$(".category_Picker_Class").css({"color":"red"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the jQuery inside a "ready" event handler for the control, as the control probably doesn't exist at the time you try to set the CSS:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(category_Picker, 'ready', function () {
    $(".category_Picker_Class .charts-menu-button-caption").css({"color":"red"});
});
```

Place the event handler in between creating the CategoryPicker and drawing the Dashboard.  [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/773jw/)

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you had `allowMultiple` set to `false`; this CSS selector would have worked if you didn't have that set.  I updated the post with the correct selector for your use case.